# What is the appropriate tag for “jbuilder” questions related to OCaml (or for that matter, Ruby on Rails)?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There's a [jbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbuilder) tag, with a description mentioning some Java-universe thing. Meanwhile, when I search for jbuilder, I seem to *mostly* get responses relating to a Ruby on Rails library for JSON.

Of course, neither of this is what I'm interested in — I'm, personally, looking for the OCaml `make`-tool.

What's the policy for disambiguating? Should I start re-tagging existing questions as [jbuilder-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbuilder-ide), [jbuilder-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbuilder-rails), and [jbuilder-ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jbuilder-ocaml), respectively? Or is there another solution in a situation like this?

(I'm happy to do some of the grunt-work here — I have high enough permissions; I just wanted to check what the proper approach is, as I haven't spent a lot of time exercising my moderator privileges on Stack Exchange, tbh.)

Comment: I like your idea a lot.  The current situation is clearly wrong.  I don't have the depth of SO meta knowledge to know whether it's the right thing to do, but it makes sense to me.  The current tag description mentions both the Java IDE and the Ruby library, which is a bad idea, of course.  It seems that the earliest questions are almost all about Ruby.  Maybe the most minimal change would be to retag only the Java and OCaml questions.  Then again, if there is a `jbuilder` tag it's likely to be misused, so maybe it makes more sense to have only `jbuilder-X` tags.

Comment: OCaml's jbuilder is going to change its name, and will eventually need a new tag, I suppose. https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/new-name-for-jbuilder/1270/2 .  It's still bad if there is one tag for both of the Java and Ruby tools.